# SP2016: Why did the + new item disappear from one list on a site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a site collection and subsite in SharePoint 2016.  I'm a SharePoint administrator so I have full access.  I can create custom lists without issue, particularly with the respect that my lists display the + new item above the list.

PersonB is a poweruser with the ability to create lists.  At first, the list seems normal, but after a while he calls me and complains that the list has lost the "+ new item or edit this list" option along with the view selection.  I see the same effect on this list.

To get by, I edit the list page's web part and change the toolbar type to "Show Toolbar".  This at least presents dropdowns of new, actions, and settings.  Oddly enough, there also appears a green + sign and add new item below the list as if it were a SharePoint 2010 experience instead of SharePoint 2016.

This list was not imported from a previous template.  The site was created new in SharePoint 2016.  Results are the same on IE, Edge, and Chrome.  Permissions are adequate and the isn't any problem on any other list in the site.

EDIT: I found my answer.  This seems kinda odd..but...  The poweruser modified the view style to be a "Basic Table".  I set it back to "Default" and we're back to the SP2016 style.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user has most likely changed the View Style to something other than Default. The "+ new item or edit this list" is only displayed with the Default view style.

[image]

Comment: You're right Mike.  I found the answer as you were answering.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but am still experiencing some issues.  The list has four views (All Items, Standard, Active and Inactive), all of them missing the +New Item and the View Menu.  Going in to modify the view I saw that the Style was set to Newsletter.  I switched them all back to Default and the Standard and Active views now have the +New Item and the View Menu, but All Item and Inactive are still missing them.  It's really confusing is there something else I should look at?  (I am a Site Admin and the user who also saw this was a Site Owner).
Thanks

Comment: what kind of list?

Comment: It was jus ta standard custom list.  Nothing special about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click ... Besides All Items
2. Create View
3. Datasheet View "View data in an editable spreadsheet format that is convenient for bulk editing and quick customization."
4. Write a name for view like BulkEdit.
   Thanks

Comment: Basically we need have a editable view "All Items" is one by default but many times new users change the settings. Best way is to Create a new "Datasheet View" for the list.